# What indices or reorganization might improve the query time of this database?

Tags: sql, join, database-performance

My database stores a list of items in a game and the relevant information about them.

The main item table contains all the fields that can only have single entries for example weight, short description, etc.

Fields which may be a set of values are represented by a table with 2 fields, item ID and attribute ID, for example the list of races which are allowed to use the item or a list of places where the item may be worn.  The one that causes a lot of extra rows in the join is the list of affects associated with an item and the value off the affect (for example: affects allowed_carrying_weight by 10 or affects hitpoints by 20 or neither or both).

Programmatically some of this is stored in 1 field by using bitfields, for example each race gets a number, if the race is allowed to use that item then `AllowedRaceInteger & 2^(raceNumber)` will be set.

For example a backpack might be held in the hand or worn on the back.  Perhaps this particular backpack may only be used by humans and elves.

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, iwt.wearlocID, i.sdesc, i.wearProg, i.isOOG, i.minLvl, i.maxLvl, 
    iaft.affectID, iaft.amount, NULL AS affectbyID FROM item i 
INNER JOIN itemwearTable iwt ON i.id=iwt.itemID 
LEFT JOIN itemaffectTable iaft ON i.id=iaft.itemID 
WHERE iwt.wearlocID >= 1 AND iwt.wearlocID <= 22 AND i.minlvl <= 50 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, iwt.wearlocID, i.sdesc, i.wearProg, i.isOOG, i.minLvl, i.maxLvl, 
    NULL AS affectID, NULL AS amount, iafbt.affectbyID FROM item i 
INNER JOIN itemwearTable iwt ON i.id=iwt.itemID 
LEFT JOIN itemaffectedbyTable iafbt ON i.id=iafbt.itemID 
WHERE iwt.wearlocID >= 1 AND iwt.wearlocID <= 22 AND i.minlvl <= 50 
ORDER BY wearlocID, sdesc,id
```

Even on a very small set of data this query can take 7-10 seconds to execute.  The only index I've set is item.id.  What criteria can I use to decide if things should be indexed?  For example should all the values in my tables that associate items with values be indexed or will this create a new problem?

Can this all be simplified with bitfield encoding somehow?  I don't imagine it can because it would require a query along the lines of select * from somewhere where somewhere.field & 256 == 1 ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Database Optimizations**

At a minimum, it's worth putting an index on `itemId` in `itemwearTable`, `itemaffectTable`, and `itemaffectedbyTable`. It's almost always a good idea to index foreign keys.

The only other candidate for an index that I see in this query is wearlocID. But, whether or not an index will make a difference will depend a lot on the cardinality of the column (i.e. how many distinct values can that column contain).

**Query Optimizations**

If the first and second query can be expected to return different results, you may gain some benefit to using `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`. `UNION` eliminates duplicates, which tends to cause the query to be sorted, which is more expensive.

You seem to be running the same basic query twice with a difference in the final join. You might benefit from using a Common-Table Expression (CTE). This allows you to run a query once and reference the results multiple times.

Implementing both suggestions would look something like this:

```
WITH src 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT i.id, 
                         iwt.wearlocid, 
                         i.sdesc, 
                         i.wearprog, 
                         i.isoog, 
                         i.minlvl, 
                         i.maxlvl 
         FROM   item i 
                inner join itemweartable iwt 
                        ON i.id = iwt.itemid 
         WHERE  iwt.wearlocid >= 1 
                AND iwt.wearlocid <= 22 
                AND i.minlvl <= 50) 
SELECT DISTINCT src.id, 
                src.wearlocid, 
                src.sdesc, 
                src.wearprog, 
                src.isoog, 
                src.minlvl, 
                src.maxlvl, 
                iaft.affectid, 
                iaft.amount, 
                NULL AS affectbyID 
FROM   src 
       left join itemaffecttable iaft 
              ON src.id = iaft.itemid 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT src.id, 
                src.wearlocid, 
                src.sdesc, 
                src.wearprog, 
                src.isoog, 
                src.minlvl, 
                src.maxlvl, 
                NULL AS affectID, 
                NULL AS amount, 
                iafbt.affectbyid 
FROM   src 
       left join itemaffectedbytable iafbt 
              ON src.id = iafbt.itemid 
ORDER  BY wearlocid, 
          sdesc, 
          id
```

**Other Notes**

You appear to be getting every row from each of these tables in this query. Is that a real use-case? If not try using a query that is closer to what you actually expect your application to run (for instance, if it will run this query for one item at a time). Generally, trying to get every row from each table is going to perform differently than more targeted queries.

Comment: This is the generic query, there are other unions that restrict the selection to far less than every row.  This is typical however on first load. I will explore CTE, I've not heard of it before (not a db professional).  I"ll try indexing and see what sort of performance changes occur.